# ToOptimizedResult and HTTP status code

Tags: servicestack

When I use `ToOptimizedResult` to return a compressed response, any custom status codes I had set for the response get reset to 200.

This works as expected:

```cs
[SetStatus(HttpStatusCode.Created, "")]
public object Post(TestCompression obj)
{
    return obj; // returns "201 Created"
}
```

These do not:

```cs
[SetStatus(HttpStatusCode.Created, "")]
public object Post(TestCompression obj)
{
    return Request.ToOptimizedResult(obj); // returns "200 OK"
}

public object Post(TestCompression obj)
{
    Response.StatusCode = 201;
    return Request.ToOptimizedResult(obj); // also returns "200 OK"
}
```

What should I be doing to ensure that the status code in a compressed response is set correctly?

I found that `ToOptimizedResult` can return a `CompressedResult` object but it's not guaranteed to do so; I can do the following to successfully override the status code but it feels wrong:

```cs
var optimized = Request.ToOptimizedResult(obj);
var compressed = optimized as CompressedResult;
if (compressed != null)
    compressed.StatusCode = HttpStatusCode.Created;
return optimized;
```

Comment: [This commit](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/commit/76e44142f291c6c54e0c81aa921e376f39033bf5) now seeds CompressionResult with the current Response Status code.